# Laravel select all rows if id exists in another table and a column has specific values on that table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables:

**notices (id, title, desc, is_published)**

**notices_to_districts (id, notice_id, district_id)**

**notices_to_employees (id, notice_id, user_id)**

**notices_to_establishments (id, notice_id, establishment_id)**

I want to get all unique notices if,

notices_to_districts  has a specific district_id, or

notices_to_employees has a specific user_id, or

notices_to_establishments has a specific establishment_id

I am trying -

```
$notices = Notice::join('notices_to_districts', 'notices_to_districts.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->join('notices_to_establishments', 'notices_to_establishments.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->join('notices_to_employees', 'notices_to_employees.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->where('district_id', '=', $user_district_id)
            ->orWhere('establishment_id', '=', $user_establishment_id)
            ->orWhere('user_id', '=', $user_id)
            ->where('is_published', '=', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Closure Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) or else, your "orWhere" will not work as you wish.

```
$notices = Notice::join('notices_to_districts', 'notices_to_districts.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->join('notices_to_establishments', 'notices_to_establishments.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->join('notices_to_employees', 'notices_to_employees.notice_id', '=', 'notices.id')
            ->where('district_id', '=', $user_district_id)
            ->where('is_published', '=', 1)            
            ->where(
                function ($query) use ($user_establishment_id, $user_id) {
                        $query->orWhere('establishment_id', '=', $user_establishment_id)
                            ->orWhere('user_id', '=', $user_id);
                }
            )
            ->get();
```

Like this example, the SQL will have the correct parentesis around your clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
     I solved it - 


$notice_ids_of_district = Notices_to_district::select('notice_id')->where('district_id', '=', $user_district_id)->get();
            $notice_ids_of_establishment = Notices_to_establishment::select('notice_id')->where('establishment_id', '=', $user_establishment_id)->get();
            $notice_ids_of_employee = Notices_to_employee::select('notice_id')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

            $notices = Notice::whereIn('id', $notice_ids_of_district)
            ->orWhereIn('id', $notice_ids_of_establishment)
            ->orWhereIn('id', $notice_ids_of_employee)
            ->get();
```